# Button action to record voices

Tags: ios, swift

I have made an app in Swift which can record voice when you tap on a button.

I want to know which action need to be implemented to record like the following example:

- When I tap on the button, the voice recorder start and
- The voice recorder record the voice till the finger releases the button

Is there a button `@IBAction` to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are aiming to apply the following scenario:

- User touched the button (and didn't release), so the recording started.
- Once the user release -or drag out of the button- recording should end.

You could achieve it by adding the following events to your recording button:

1- Add `touchDown` event => User touched the button (and didn't release), so the recording started.

2- Add `touchUpInside` event => Once the user release recording should end.

3- Add `touchDragExit` event => or drag out of the button.

It should be similar to this:

```
@IBAction func touchDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Start recording")
}

@IBAction func touchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Stop recording")
}

@IBAction func touchDragExit(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Stop recording")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LongPressGestureRecognizer method for start and stop recording the voice

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let longGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("handleLongTapOnButton:")))
    btnRecordVoice.addGestureRecognizer(longGestureRecognizer)
}

func handleLongTapOnButton(sender : UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("Long tap is handled")
    if sender.state == .began {
        print("UILongPressGestureRecognizerStateBegan so start the recording voice here")
        //write the function for start recording the voice here
    }
    else if sender.state == .ended {
        print("UILongPressGestureRecognizerStateEnded so stop the recording voice here")
        //write the function for stop recording the voice here
    }
}
```

Comment: If you move your touched location on screen it will repeat the task