# Swift - LongPress Gesture on Button to record Audio with AVFoundation

Tags: swift, uibutton, avfoundation, long-press, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I'm trying to implement a record button for my chat, which records as long as you hold the button. I implemented a longpressGestureRecognizer, but unfortunately it only records for one second, no matter how long I press.

Here is the code:

```
let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
    longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1


    self.recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try self.recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try self.recordingSession.setActive(true)
        self.recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    self.record_button.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
                } else {
                    // failed to record!
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // failed to record!
    }

// Gesture Recognizer for the Record Button, so as long as it is pressed, record!
func longPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        print("long press ended")
        let recordImage = UIImage(named: "ic_mic_white")
        record_button.setImage(recordImage, for: .normal)
        self.recordTapRelease()
    }
    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        let recordingTapImage = UIImage(named: "ic_mic_none_white")
        record_button.setImage(recordingTapImage, for: .normal)
        self.recording()

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I implemented the .touchdown .touchupinside events etc. 
I still get the same behaviour, unless I slight up above the record button leaving the orange view. Then the recording image button image also changes, showing recording, and if I release and move further up it stops recording.

[image: Recording button function]

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue to your satisfaction?  If you did would you please share how you achieved the desired results?  I am trying to do the same thing and would love some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to create `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for achieving this; You can do it by implementing `touchDown`, `touchUpInside` and `touchDragExit` events for a UIButton.

At the first look, it might seems that it's more complicated than working with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, but I *think* that it is more logical and even more readable.

Follow the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173205/button-action-to-record-voices/40173826#40173826) and hopefully you will get the desired behavior for your recording button. It also has another answer if you insist to use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: It helped but it still does not work properly. Check my edit